# How to delete images with suffix from folder in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have stored multiple sizes of the image on s3.
e.g. image100_100,image200_200,image300_150;

I want to delete the specific size of images like images with suffix 200_200 from the folder. there are a lot of images in this folder so how to delete these images?

Comment: Ok, through what? A lambda function? If so, in what language (Python, Java, Go etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use AWS command-line interface (AWS CLI):

```
aws s3 rm s3://Path/To/Dir/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*200_200"
```

We first exclude everything, then include what we need to delete. This is a workaround to mimic the behavior of `rm -r "*200_200"` command in Linux.

Comment: Thanks, It's working just needed to add the extension as "200x200.jpeg"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to write a Python script, similar to:

```
import boto3

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
PREFIX = '' # eg 'images/'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

# Get a list of objects
list_response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket = BUCKET, Prefix = PREFIX)

while True:
    # Find desired objects to delete
    objects = [{'Key':object['Key']} for object in list_response['Contents'] if object['Key'].endswith('200_200')]
    print ('Deleting:', objects)

    # Delete objects
    if len(objects) > 0:
        delete_response = s3_client.delete_objects(
            Bucket=BUCKET,
            Delete={'Objects': objects}
        )

    # Next page
    if list_response['IsTruncated']:
        list_response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(
            Bucket = BUCKET,
            Prefix = PREFIX,
            ContinuationToken=list_reponse['NextContinuationToken'])
    else:
        break
```